# Cannot figure out how to utilize "| Where-Object {$_.Name -like "ada*"} in Namespace:System.Management.Automation

Tags: c#, powershell

Namespace:System.Management.Automation

Trying to do where-object matches in `C#` using `Powershell` in the Automation namespace

Tried this, but it returns -like as an unknown parameter

```
PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create("Get-Childitem").
                                    AddCommand("where-object { $_.Name -like "*a" }");
```

Comment: Try using single quote characters `$_.Name -like '*a' ` because you use double quotes around the whole `Where-Object` command.

Comment: @Theo have tried this... no cigar